# event.target.value omitting last character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

i've been solving this problem without any progress for the pas 2 hours or so, here is code:

```
export const useFetchAll = () => {
  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState("");
  const [listToDisplay, setListToDisplay] = useState([]);

  // const debouncedSearch = useDebounce(searchItem, 300);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchItem(e.target.value);

    if (searchItem === "") {
      setListToDisplay([]);
    } else {
      setListToDisplay(
        searchResult.filter((item) => {
          return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase());
        })
      );
    }
    console.log(searchItem);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchRepo = async () => {
      setLoading(true);

      const { data } = await axios.get("https://api.github.com/repositories");
      setSearchResult(data);

      setLoading(false);
    };

    if (searchItem) searchRepo();
  }, [searchItem]);
```

the problem is that when i enter characters in input and set state to event.target.value it doesn't pick up last character. here is an image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz6YF.png)

BTW this is a custom hook, i return the onchange function here:

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const { searchResult, loading, searchItem, handleChange, listToDisplay } =
    useFetchAll();
```

and then pass it as a prop to a component like so:

```
        <Stack spacing={2}>
          <Search searchItem={searchItem} handleChange={handleChange} />
        </Stack>
      </Container>
```

any help? thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember, setSearchItem(e.target.value); is async. You cannot log the value after you've called the state setter. You can use the e.target.value directly instead.

Comment: Is this the full code of the useFetchAll hook?

Comment: no i return these things: return {
    searchItem,
    handleChange,
    searchResult,
    loading,
    listToDisplay,
  };

Comment: yea but that doesnt help because i have to press extra button to perform a search for example when in search bar i type: ruby
i have to press extra button to perform actual search on ruby like so: rubya would preform search and e.target.value would be ruby

Comment: here is github repo if that helps https://github.com/ikkakoo/search-github-repos-app-

Comment: What is the searchResult used for?

Comment: searchResult is a data returned by axios api call. then i'm filtering that data according to what searchItem is so for example user enters 'ruby' in a search bar searchResult is filtered and if any name includes 'ruby' returns new array which is listToDisplay

Comment: Yes, sorry! I meant why are you exporting it from the hook? What's its use outside the hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling the `searchItem` and `searchResult` state variables as if their state change was synchronous (via `setSearchItem` and `setSearchResult`) but it isn't! **React state setters are asynchronous**.

The `useEffect` callback has a dependency on the `searchItem` state variable. Now every time the user types something, the state will change, that change will trigger a re-rendering of the Component and **after** that render finishes, the `side-effect` (the `useEffect` callback) will be executed due to the Components' [lifecycle](https://wavez.github.io/react-hooks-lifecycle/).

In our case, we don't want to initiate the fetch request on the next render, but right at the moment that the user enters something on the search input field, that is when the `handleChange` gets triggered.

In order to make the code work as expected, we need some a more structural refactoring.

You can get rid of the `useEffect` and handle the flow through the `handleChange` method:

```
export const useFetchAll = () => {

  const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState( false );
  const [ searchItem, setSearchItem ] = useState( "" );
  const [ listToDisplay, setListToDisplay ] = useState( [] );

  const handleChange = async ( e ) => {

    const { value } = e.target;
    // Return early if the input is an empty string:
    setSearchItem( value );
    if ( value === "" ) {
      return setListToDisplay( [] );
    }
    setLoading( true );
    const { data } = await axios.get( "https://api.github.com/repositories" );
    setLoading( false );
    const valueLowercase = value.toLowerCase(); // Tiny optimization so that we don't run the toLowerCase operation on each iteration of the filter process below
    setListToDisplay(
        data.filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase().includes(valueLowercase))
    );
  };

  return {
      searchItem,
      handleChange,
      loading,
      listToDisplay,
  };
};
```

Comment: @ikkako By the way, you can replace const [reposPerPage] = useState(6); in the HomePage component with a regular variable. No need for a state variable there. const reposPerPage = 6;

Comment: does that arise performance issues?

Comment: so if im not using setState and the variable doesnt need to change it is better to use regular variables?

Comment: Exactly! @ikkako When you are not interested in a variable retaining its value across renders or triggering a render upon updating, then you can always use a normal variable. Performance is impacted when you are over-using state variables or using them without needing to, not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

function used for updating state value is asynchronous that why your state variable is showing previous value and not the updated value.
I have made some change you can try running the  below code .

```
    const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState("");
    const [listToDisplay, setListToDisplay] = useState([]);

    // const debouncedSearch = useDebounce(searchItem, 300);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
      setSearchItem(e.target.value); // this  sets value asyncronously   
      console.log("e.target.value  :" +  e.target.value); // event.target.value does not    omitting last character
      console.log("searchItem  :" + searchItem);    // if we check the value then it is not set. it will update asyncronously  
    
    };

    const setList = async () => {
      if (searchItem === "") {
        setListToDisplay([]);
      } else {
        setListToDisplay(
          searchResult.filter((item) => {
            return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase());
          })
        );
      }
    };


    const searchRepo = async () => { 
      const { data } = await axios.get("https://api.github.com/repositories");
      setSearchResult(data);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    // this useeffect execute its call back when searchItem  changes a
    useEffect(() => {
      setList();  // called here to use previous value  stored in 'searchResult'   and display something ( uncomment it if you want to display only updated value )
      if (searchItem) searchRepo();
    }, [searchItem]);


    // this useeffect execute when axios set fetched data in 'searchResult' 
    useEffect(() => {
      setList();   
    }, [searchResult]);


    // this useeffect execute when   data is updated  in 'listToDisplay'
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("filtered Data") // final  'listToDisplay'  will be availble here
      console.log(listToDisplay)
    }, [listToDisplay]);
```

Comment: i'll try to explore what you've done here. max thanks!

Comment: Instead of introducing more useEffects and more re-renders, we can get rid of the useEffect and run the whole operation in one go, inside the handleChange function. Apart from introducing more renders, this suggested refactoring introduces more complexity and makes the code harder to read and reason about.

Comment: Agree with @Kostas This has lots of dependencies of variables between different functions making it hard to follow.

Comment: Overcomplicated